# unexpected turn of the camera (three.js + tween + lookat)

Tags: three.js, tween.js

I have a question about three.js + tween + lookat
Here's an example: https://intera3d.ru/tween_test/tokyo.html
I want that when the button "TWEEN" is pressed the camera looked at the 3D model from above.

And so it happens, but at the end there is an unexpected turn of the camera / 3D model.

How can you avoid this?

Here is the "tween" function code:

```
function TWEEN_begin_CAMERA_1() {

    const tweenCamera1 = new TWEEN.Tween( 
        {x: camera.position.x, y: camera.position.y, z: camera.position.z, 
            lookAtX: 0, lookAtY: 0, lookAtZ: 0} 
        )
    .to( {x: 0, y: 20, z: 0, lookAtX: 0, lookAtY: 0, lookAtZ: 0}, 1000 )

    const updateCamera = function (object, elapsed) {
        camera.position.set(object.x, object.y, object.z);
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(object.lookAtX, object.lookAtY, object.lookAtZ))
    }
    tweenCamera1.onUpdate(updateCamera)
    tweenCamera1.start()
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with [`THREE.Spherical`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Spherical), that doesn't allow camera to be set at `x`=0 and `z`=0 (at any `y`), see in the docs what the method `.makeSafe()` does:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_Tween" style="position:absolute; margin: 10px;">TWEENME</button>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.134.0";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.134.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import {TWEEN} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.134.0/examples/jsm/libs/tween.module.min.js"

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 5, 10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
});

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.setScalar(1);
scene.add(light, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));


scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper());
scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5), 
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
    {
      map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg")
    }
  )
));

btn_Tween.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
  let spherical = new THREE.Spherical();
  spherical.setFromVector3(camera.position);
  spherical.radius = 20;
  spherical.phi = 0;
  spherical.makeSafe();
  let v = new THREE.Vector3().setFromSpherical(spherical);
  let t = new TWEEN.Tween(camera.position).to(v, 2000).onUpdate(() => {
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    controls.update();
  });
  t.start();
});

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  TWEEN.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

https://intera3d.ru/tween_test/tokyo2.html
Works perfect now (button TWEEN2)
It's on the axis Y (top view)
How can we also do it along other axes? -Y, +X, -X, +Z, -Z ?

And how to smoothly unfold a scene / 3D object?
That is, do the same as when you click on the button TWEEN
but do it smoothly?

Comment: @RuslanKarimov The solution is intended to solve the cases, when you put camera strictly on Y-axis (either +Y or -Y), for X and Z axis you don't need that trick with `Spherical`. If the answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted. For the topic about "unfolding" of a scene/object, make a new question, putting more details in description of the problem.